# How to install and connect PHP with Oracle on RedHat 6

Tags: php, linux, oracle, apache, redhat

I need to maintain a project for another person. This project connects PHP with Oracle, but when I set it up on Redhat, the system shows this error:

> Call to undefined function oci_connect() in ...

I think I'm missing OCI8 extention and need to install it.

I read and tried [this link](http://miao5.blogspot.com/2011/10/enabling-php-oci8-extension-on-linux.html), but I can't run `yum install php-devel` because Redhat shows that I do not have this package.

Comment: this is not very well put question: see other questions and edit it. I'm missing what have you done (how and what did you install), put the full error stack trace ...

Comment: Sorry for my question. please see it again, thanks you

Comment: try yum search php-devel if it doesn't exist you need to find in which repository it is located and add the repository into your yum. if you do not work with linux - can be challanging task